# std::expected and reference return type

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to use the proposed `std::expected` or some variation of the technique to replace my exception-using code, but I can't figure out how to use it in functions that return references in the current implementation. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Please don't tell me I should be using exceptions. I can't in this case, and the why of it is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but can't you have a `std::expected<std::reference_wrapper<yourType>, fail_reason>>`?

Comment: I could see this evolving into `namespace std { template<typename T, typename E> using expected_ref = std::expected<std::reference_wrapper<T>, E>; }`

Comment: You may be interested in Boost [Outcome](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/outcome/doc/html/faq.html), as an interim alternative to `std::expected`.  Especially if you're already using Boost.

Comment: <https://wg21.link/p0323r12#expected-references>: you may be able to in the future (probably not C++2b)